# Spring 5 application not showing static html pages

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am creating a small Spring 5 Web Application, NOT a Spring Boot application.  For this small work project, this is both the front-end (UI) and the back-end with RESTful API (Controllers).
I have done this before, so I thought I wouldn't have any problem making a web-app that had RESTful endpoints, but also able to server out some static content.  The problem is that my RESTful API's work, but the static content is not coming up and is a 404 Not Found issue.

I've gone out to the internet where I see a lot of older messages and articles.  Even here on StackOverflow, a lot of the messages are older.  Even though this is not Spring Boot, I am using annotations in the code, and I am trying to use the proper Java Configuration classes and not an applicationContext.html file.   So many of the old messages and articles refer to classes that are long since deprecated and gone.  I just hope I am not in the same position again.

Here is the Spring 5 Configuration start:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.tomholmes.app")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyAppConfig. {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContainerInitializer initializer() {
    return new ServletContainerInitializer()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
            ctx.setInitParameter("isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled", "true");
            ctx.setInitParameter("log4jConfiguration", "classpath:log4j2.xml");
            ctx.setInitParameter("log4jContextName", "My App");
           }
       };
   }
}
```

Here is the Web Configuration, this should be pointing to the right place:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

And here is my structure as it is exploded from the WAR file:

```
/src/main/java/com/tomholmes/app
/src/main/resources
/src/main/resources/static
/src/main/resources/static/index.html
/src/main/resources/static/css/mine.css
/src/main/resources/static/js/myjavascript.js
```

I am using Gradle, not maven, to build this app at work, and it builds successfully.
I am deploying the WAR file to the Tomcat 9 webapps directory, and I can start Tomcat up.
I can see Tomcat running, the app is exploded/deployed and I can see the exploded files.

```
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/com
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/static
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/static/css
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/static/index.html
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/static/js
/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib
```

I can see from the Tomcat Manager that the app is running, I can go to that, and there is not page that comes up from:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/     and there is no page.
```

So, when I try to call:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.html
```

I was expecting something to be there, and again, there is a 404 Error -  Not Found.

If there is any more information I can provide, please let me know.   I really hope that this is something simple I can fix quickly.   I can't imagine that this would be a hard fix.

Thanks!